# Android sqlite creating database error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

i am newbie with android sqlite database. now i just try to create my custom database manager and i got the error at oncreate() function. I already spent 3 days to figure it out but unfortunately i am still stuck in it. Any brilliant idea would be appreciate.

```
public class DBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static Context myContext;
public static final String DB_NAME = "goldenland.db";
public static final String TB_CAT = "tbl_categories";
public static final String TB_ARTICLE = "tbl_articles";
public static final String TB_SUBCAT = "tbl_subcategories";
public static final String TB_SCHEDULE = "tbl_schedule";
public static final String TB_CONTENT = "tbl_contents";
public static final String TB_CITY = "tbl_cities";
public static final String name = "name";
public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.gokiri.goldenland/databases/";

public DBManager(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    DBManager.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExit = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExit) {
        System.out.println("Testing");
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }

    if (checkDb != null) {
        checkDb.close();
    }
    return checkDb != null ? true : false;
}

public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("goldenland_2.sqlite");

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDatabase() throws SQLiteException {

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}
```

[image: Error Log Cat]

Comment: You shouldn't save contexts statically. If you access this code from multiple activities its likely you will get a crash.

Comment: so how could i use this code from multiple activities. Does it concern with phone read/write access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things might be wrong. Does your database really exist in res/assets? Are you writing to the correct directory? Stepping through with the debugger would go a long way toward diagnosing the problem.

You might get a sanity check by having `copyDatabase` take a `String` argument, which would be `this.getReadableDatabase().getPath()`. You might even try writing that out to the log to see if you're writing to the correct database directory.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to check.
1. in method `checkDataBase` open the database in `OPEN_READONLY` mode.
2. this is very important check that the size of the database is less than 1 mb. Android version previous to 3.0 don't allow file copy of more than 1 mb.

**Update:**
You will need to split the database file into parts of 1Mb each, copy all parts one by one and join them together again. refer to following [link](http://www.chriskopec.com/blog/2010/mar/13/deploying-android-apps-with-large-databases/)

Comment: my database file size is larger than 1 MB and now i am working on Android 2.1 based, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

unless you didnt put up all your code, it seems to me that you are missing somethings. I used this tutorial and had no problems

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954

hope that helps